# iTerm2 does not kill processes when tab is closed

Tags: iterm

If I work in terminal, and, say run `rails server` in it attached to the current terminal and then close the tab it will not terminate the process making it hang around indefinitely without ability to bring it. Is it possible to fix it?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open new terminal tab (`cmd + t`);
2. Run a process in it (e.g. `irb`);
3. Close the tab (`cmd + w`);
4. List processes to see that `irb` is still running (`ps ax|grep irb`).

Quitting iTerm doesn't finish these processes either.

Comment: If you Quit iTerm2 will it not quit all processes?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes, it wouldn't quit them. I've just added steps to reproduce to question.

Comment: Do you have tmux integration turned on? If so, it's probably creating tmux sessions for every tab you open. Try `tmux list-sessions` and see what it comes back with.

Comment: @JayThompson I don't use tmux, but I have it installed, list-sessions tells me `failed to connect to server: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hm. Does it also happen for non-Ruby processes? e.g. `top`

Comment: same for me, just installed iterm2 and appreciated the features and right after that ran into several major bugs (what a shame)

Answer (score 8):

I think it is supposed to be a feature instead of a problem.

Generally, to kill a process or just exit the current shell session, you should not use "cmd+w" or click the close button of the window. Instead, you should use "ctrl-c" and "ctrl-d" respectively.

Besides, the following facts may help you,

- You can use "cmd+z" to fully restore a tab right after it is closed
- The attached session and tasks keep run in background right after you close a tab. You can restore the tab at this point. But if you open a new tab using "cmd+t" now, the background session in the previously closed tab will be killed.

So the "restorable tab closing" is a feature of iterm2, though quite confusing.

Comment: you have only 5 seconds to undo before iterm2 kills process for real though

Comment: @igor You can change the time limit. The default is 5 seconds, but this is a configurable feature in the iTerm2 Preferences / Profiles / Session / "Undo" can revive a session that has been closed for up to `5` seconds

Answer (score -2):

I know its super old, but incase anyone else comes across this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> worked for me in iterm2