# How to prevent "Do you want to terminate running processes" window when shutting down?

Tags: terminal, mac, shutdown

When I have running processes on my terminal and I try to shutdown Mac, I get this window:

[image]

I want all running processes to terminate automatically when I shut down my Mac without being prompted the window shown above. Is there a way to do that?

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Edit: My question is not about iTerm2 or closing tabs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTerm2 does not kill processes when tab is closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144955/iterm2-does-not-kill-processes-when-tab-is-closed)

Comment: Any open app could prompt you do you want no prompts at all or just terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terminal Preferences → Profiles, select the profile you're using (probably marked Default) in the sidebar on the left, then choose Shell. Under ‘**Ask before closing:**’, choose **Never**.

[image]

Comment: and again learned something +1, who said you can not teach old dog new tricks

Comment: Or add `Python` to the list, and that way you don't prevent other process from accidentally terminating early that you may want a warning about.